# Finding a highest megapixel camera for PC

Tags: camera

How can i have a PC camera/webcam that have high quality as a portable camera, like the Nikon D800 have 35 MP. I can't find a PC camera that have the same Megapixel ? Even the Microsoft Lifecam have only 2MP and it's not my choice :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about scientific imaging, not audio-video production.

Comment: @AJHenderson ok, it's a bit relevant when i show my purpose. But the main problem is a camera/webcam for PC, so i have edited the question

Comment: It's unfortunately still not a good question as it asks to find the highest MP camera which is a shopping question and still off topic as it will change every time a new, higher MP camera comes out that supports tethering with a computer.

Comment: Please note that many people take the megapixels specification as proportional to the image quality, but that is incorrect.

Higher megapixel cameras require smaller pixel sensors (as there are more of them on the sensor). Smaller pixel sensors mean less photons are hitting each sensor, thus producing more noise.

High megapixel specs are important mainly if the image is to be printed in large scale (billboards, etc.). But for highest quality small images a lower mega pixel camera may well produce a better image.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is a DSLR with a lens mount for the microscope.  It goes in places of the eyepiece and generally does not have the diopter from an eyepiece (so magnification is a bit lower, but you can also zoom in).  Among standard size DSLRs, the highest megapixel one I'm aware of at this time is the Nikon D800 at 35 megapixels, but there may be bigger out there now.

Comment: How can i have a PC camera that have high quality as the Nikon D800?

Comment: @ĐứcUltraSoft -- As AJ says, the best way to do that is to _use the Nikon D800_.

Comment: @mattdm but i need a camera/webcam directly for computer. It must be show directly in computer instead of a portable camera.

Comment: @ĐứcUltraSoft You can connect a DSLR to a computer. This is called "tethering".

Comment: @ĐứcUltraSoft - As mattdm already pointed out, a DSLR can be tethered to a computer using drivers for the camera and photos can be taken directly on the computer.  You also want a camera that supports an interchangeable lens system so that you can properly rig it to a microscope, otherwise the effective resolution of the image the camera is seeing will be less than that of the resolution of the camera.  (And honestly, there is a decent chance that it will be anyway, depending on the quality of microscope you are using and the level of magnification.)